Getting error status 404 not found when subscribing to a Movesense device
When trying to subscribe to a measure on a Movesense device - like HR - I get a 404 NOT FOUND error.   I'm using the mdsflutter Flutter plugin, an iOS phone, and an MD Movesense device.  Iam using mdsflutter 2.1.1 as a flutter package  and trying to integrate with the Awario Device and trying to read the the RR intervals from device.
Could Please help us to solve this issue and get the RR intervals from the movesense Device....                                                                                                        

ERROR:

I/Komposti( 4961): Adding EventListener for path: suunto://MDS/EventListener
E/Komposti( 4961): [SDS RESPONSE] type: POST status: NOT_FOUND header: {"TaskId": 14, "Content-Length": 0, "Uri": "suunto://MDS/EventListener", "Reason": "NOT_FOUND", "Status": 404}
D/MdsOperationHandler( 4961): SDSInternalCallback with call type: 4 header: {"TaskId": 14, "Content-Length": 0, "Uri": "suunto://MDS/EventListener", "Reason": "NOT_FOUND", "Status": 404}```



Sample Code:

final String HEART_RATE_PATH = "/Meas/HR";
  static const String URI_EVENTLISTENER = "suunto://MDS/EventListener";
  StreamSubscription? _hrSubscription;


 _hrSubscription = MdsAsync.subscribe(URI_EVENTLISTENER,
            formatContractToJson(DeviceSerialNumber, HEART_RATE_PATH))
        .listen((event) {
      Map<String, dynamic> body = event["Body"];
      final rrData = body['rrData'] as List<dynamic>;

      // Access the first RR interval data point
      final rrValue = rrData.isNotEmpty ? rrData[0] : null;

      if (rrValue != null) {
        print("RR [ms]: $rrValue");
        rrIntervalList.add(rrValue); // Add to RR interval list
      }
    });
  }


Have you checked the example in mdsflutter?
https://github.com/petri-lipponen-movesense/mdsflutter/tree/master/example

@PetriL
Yes, I have tried the GitHub code you mentioned, and the code above is referenced from it. Additionally, i have tried configuring same code from mdsflutter GitHub repository However, when running the Flutter GitHub example, no devices appear in the list during scanning

Did you make sure that all the permissions are also the same as in mdsflutter example?

yes, I cross verify all the permissions
